# split the special charater contain inside the string

Tags: java

I have a String `"""JBL@gmail.com` from which I want to remove the `"""` which is located at the front of the email address. I tried to use `split`, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
     String [] sender1 = SA1.split(" ");
     String str1 = sender1[0];
     System.out.println("the str1 is :"+str1);
     String [] sender2 = str1.split("\\\"");

     String str2 = sender2[0];
     String str3 = sender2[1];

     System.out.println("the str2 is :"+str2);
     System.out.println("the str3 is :"+str3);
```

Here is my code output-

```
the str1 is :"""JBL@gmail.com""
the str2 is :
the str3 is :
```

My SA1 will contain `"""JBL@gmail.com"" <JBL@gmail.com>"`. The email address can be a mix of lower/upper case letters, numbers, and etc.

Comment: Why don't you want to do something like this `string.replaceAll("\"","");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **SA1** does in fact contain

```
"\"\"\"JBL@gmail.com\"\" <JBL@gmail.com>\""
```

then you can use [**Pattern/Matcher**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) with a [**Regular Expression**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) of `"<(.*?)>"` to retrieve the E-Mail Address from the String:

```
String sa1 = "\"\"\"JBL@gmail.com\"\" <JBL@gmail.com>\"";
String email = "";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sa1);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Is a match found? 
    if (!matcher.group(1).equals("")) { 
        // There is so place the match into the 
        // email variable.
        email = matcher.group(1); 
    }
}
// Display the E-Mail Address in Console Window.
System.out.println("E-Mail Address is:  " + email);
```

Console window will display:

```
E-Mail Address is:  JBL@gmail.com
```

**Regular Expression Explanation:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the email in the first part of the string by removing all quotation marks (`replace("\"", "")`), spliting by spaces (`split(" ")`), and taking the first element in the split (`[0]`):

```
String str = "\"\"\"JBL@gmail.com\"\" <JBL@gmail.com>\"";
str.replace("\"", "").split(" ")[0];
```

Note that the second element would produce `<JBL@gmail.com>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"fdsd\"\"\" dsd".split("\"\"\"")
```

you have to use

```
"yourWords".split("\"\"\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String  s= "\"\"\"JBL@gmail.com\"\" <JBL@gmail.com>\"".
                split("<")[1].replace(">", "").replace("\"", "");
```